# How would you write this C# code (that uses the yield keyword) succinctly in Ruby?

Tags: c#, ruby, linq, translation

Is there a good way to emulate `yield` in Ruby? I'm interested in writing similar 'infinite fib sequence' in Ruby.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace cs2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {          
          var i=Fibs().TakeWhile(x=>x < 1000).Where(x=>x % 2==0).Sum();
        }

        static IEnumerable<long> Fibs() {
            long a = 0, b = 1;
            while (true) {
                yield return b;
                b += a;
                a = b - a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it is possible, please give an example.

Comment: When one says "Do you know what time it is? " He expects the time, not the "I do" answer, so your irony is a bit groundless.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. If I had any ruby skillz I'd answer it

Comment: Usually, I tend to answer "Yes" at this very question too.

Comment: *cough* "Be Nice" http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: does Ruby have anything like LINQ? that stuff would make this question hard if not.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282615/ruby-equivalent-of-cs-yield-keyword-or-creating-sequences-without-prealloca

Comment: After the last edit of this question, it appears to me as a duplicate of the question referenced by Mladen right above this comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The common idiom in ruby to implement such sequences, is to define a method that executes a block for each element in the sequence if one is given or return an enumerator if it is not. That would look like this:

```
def fibs
  return enum_for(:fibs) unless block_given?
  a = 0
  b = 1
  while true
    yield b
    b += a
    a = b - a
  end
end

fibs
#=> #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x7f030eb37988>
fibs.first(20)
#=> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765]
fibs.take_while {|x| x < 1000}.select {|x| x%2 == 0}
#=> [2, 8, 34, 144, 610]
fibs.take_while {|x| x < 1000}.select {|x| x%2 == 0}.inject(:+)
=> 798
```

Answer (score 2):

[Fibonacci numbers with Ruby 1.9 Fibers](http://www.davidflanagan.com/2007/08/fibonacci-numbers-with-ruby-19-fibers.html):

```
fib = Fiber.new do 
  x, y = 0, 1
  loop do 
    Fiber.yield y
    x,y = y,x+y
  end
end

20.times { puts fib.resume }
```